# Get 'active from' attribute from category in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, categories, magento-1.7

There are pre-defined attributes in Mangento 1.7 categories named

- active from
- active to

I can fetch Name of the current product's category using this:

```
 $productId=$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getId(), 'id');
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
 $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
 foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
 $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
 echo $_cat->getName();
 } ?>
```

but I need to find the active from date of current category also. 
How do I fetch this?

Comment: I have found attributes like getName() and getThumbnail() which work perfectly but getActiveFrom() does not work!

Comment: Try to dump the data: Zend_Debug::dump($product->getData()); and check if the key exists for active from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably worth noting that these values are for the active state of a custom design for the category, and not the actual active state of the category itself...

**As an array together:**

```
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$_customDesignDates = $_cat->getCustomDesignDate();
```

**Or individually:**

```
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$fromDate = $_cat->getData('custom_design_from');
$toDate = $_cat->getData('custom_design_to');
```

Comment: will you leave some questions for us to answer? :D

Comment: Sorry :) Seriously though, you are right - I have been spending too much time on here recently!